# Compare float value

Tags: objective-c

I try to compare float value but I can't do it, I use this code:

```
float a = [[array objectAtIndex:(i+1)] floatValue];
float b = [[array objectAtIndex:(i)] floatValue];

a = [[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%.2f",a] floatValue];
b = [[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%.2f",b] floatValue];
step = [[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%.2f",step] floatValue];

float newStep = a-b;

if (newStep != step) {
      NSLog(@"NewStep: %f Step: %f",newStep,step);
}
```

this is the output:

```
2013-04-28 19:07:57.396 Pro[24265:c07] NewStep: 0.220000 Step: 0.220000
2013-04-28 19:07:57.397 Pro[24265:c07] NewStep: 0.220000 Step: 0.220000
2013-04-28 19:07:57.397 Pro[24265:c07] NewStep: 0.220000 Step: 0.220000
2013-04-28 19:07:57.397 Pro[24265:c07] NewStep: 2.420000 Step: 0.220000
2013-04-28 19:07:57.397 Pro[24265:c07] NewStep: 0.220000 Step: 0.220000
2013-04-28 19:07:57.397 Pro[24265:c07] NewStep: 0.220000 Step: 0.220000
```

obviously don't work, where is the mistake? the code seems to be correct!

Comment: Where do you assign to `step` for the first time? Also, the easier (and possibly working) comparison would be `abs(a - b - step) < 0.005`.

Comment: Try Googling around for "comparing floating point numbers"; there are lots of tricky bits.

Comment: step is a parameter, however thank you! I use this comparison and now it work!

Answer (score 4):

Never ever compare float variables for equality! Floats are an approximation only, due to the limited accuracy. Use

```
if (fabs(a-b)<0.0001) {...
```

or something similar, if you want to check for equality.